# I just fired a mug (cone 5/6 B-Mix clay) in my kiln and there is a 2 inch crack along the bottom. Is there any way to save this by glazing it?

Tags: restoration, ceramics, clay

I just unloaded a bisque fire and noticed that a mug (made from B-Mix cone 5/6 Laguna clay) has a 2 inch crack on the bottom. Is there any way to fix the crack my using glaze?

Comment: What is the purpose of the mug? To hold a few dry sticks and call it art, or to hold water? Or maybe other chemicals (e.g., alcohol)? The answer greatly depends on this.

Comment: I would like to hold liquid within the mug but if that isn't possible with a glaze fix then it may just have to be a pot

Comment: I cannot encourage you either pro or against fixing with glaze. I am myself a be-on-the-safe-side kind of guy, so I would probably redo the mug entirely. And use the first one as support for some dry art :)